# Track manually installed packages

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to track and list all the packages that I installed manually, with `pip install <pkg>`.

The motivation is a cleaner upgrade of python. Right now, the suggested method is:

```
pip freeze > reqs.txt
pip install -r reqs.txt
pip-review --auto
```

It will blindly install all the packages that I currently have. However, in practice, they weren't many of them, and most of the packages are dependencies. If I could have a short list, I'd be able to prune packages that I'm not using anymore.